# Erro ao utilizar o pacote plm - Error in x[, !na.check] : (subscript) logical subscript too long

Tags: r

Estou utilizando o pacote plm para fazer análises em um painel. Para estruturar a base como painel, utilizei a função `pdata.frame` do mesmo pacote. Com isso, tive como retorno um painel com as seguinte características:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dai, eu gostaria de rodar uma regressão utilizando variáveis instrumentais com a seguinte formula:

```
saida <- plm(formula = X4  ~  X1 | . ~  X2 + X3 + Ano.Mes + id, data = as.matrix(painel),model = "within", index = c("id", "Ano.Mes"))
```

No entanto, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Error in x[, !na.check] : (subscript) logical subscript too long

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para solucionar esse erro?

Eu criei esse exemplo com a estrutura de dados Iris da base do R e ocorre o mesmo erro:

```
data(iris)
tst <- iris[1:120,]
tst$mes <- rep(1:12,times = 10)
tst$ano <- unlist(lapply(2007:2016, function(x) rep(x, times = 12)))
tst$ano.mes <- paste(tst$ano,"m",tst$mes, sep = "")
painel <- pdata.frame(tst, index = c("Species","ano.mes"))
modelo <- plm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | . ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species + ano.mes, data = as.matrix(painel), index = c("Species", "mes.ano"), model = "within")
```

Comment: Seria interessante se pudéssemos reproduzir o teu código, a fim de verificar que erro se encontra nele. Sem ter acesso a mais informações, a minha hipótese é que que o vetor lógico `na.check` possui mais elementos do que o número de colunas de `x`. Entretanto, não sei o que é `x`, nem como `na.check` foi construído. Por isso, sugiro que a pergunta seja editada e mais detalhes sobre ela sejam incluídos.

Comment: tem algum motivo para transformar o `painel` em `matrix` no código? Acho estranho você transformá-lo para `pdata.frame` e depois usar `data = as.matrix(painel)`. Isso não acaba desfazendo a transformação?

Comment: 1) Seria muito trabalhoso divulgar meus dados aqui para análise ser feita sobre eles, dai eu criei um exemplo com a base de dados "iris" da base do R. Coloquei no mesmo formato que meus dados e rodei o modelo, tendo o mesmo erro. (Esse código ta na resposta abaixo)


2) Eu faço o pdata.frame basicamente para criar o rownames. O as.matrix é utilizado, pois o plm pede que a estrutura de dados de input seja uma matriz. No final do código, temos uma matrix com o rownames de um painel..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom vejo aqui que o erro pode ser devido ao fato de estar sendo definido duas formulas onde deveria estar apenas uma defina.

```
modelo <- plm(formula = Sepal.Length **~** Sepal.Width | .  **~** Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species + ano.mes, data = (painel), index = c("Species", "mes.ano"), model = "within")
```

o item "." remete a formula definida anteriormente.

Pode ser visto mais sobre isso em https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf

> 4.3. Formulas
>   There are circumstances where standard formula are not very usefull to > describe a model,
>   notably while using instrumental variable like estimators: to deal with  these situations, we
>   use the Formula package.
>   The Formula package provides a class which unables to construct multipart formula, each
>   part being separated by a pipe sign. plm provides a pFormula object which is a Formula with specific methods.

O utilizando o problema que o amigo Daniel abordou e o problema que estou apontando uma solução possível é:

```
modelo <- plm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | . + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species + ano.mes, data = (painel), index = c("Species", "mes.ano"), model = "within")
```

espero ter ajudado.
Abraços

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema é:

1. o pacote recebe um data.frame como input. Isso pode ser encontrado na documentação.

> data   a data.frame,

2. Quando você está ajustando o modelo com a matriz, ele dá este erro. Quando você ajusta o modelo com o data.frame, ele dá o seguinte erro. Provavelmente por isso você pensou que o input deveria ser uma matriz.

> Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data
>   = data,  :    object is not a matrix

Isso é um problema de antes de rodar o modelo. Esse erro está na função que transforma a sua formula em uma matriz que será consumida pelo modelo em seguida. Ou seja, não é um problema específico do pacote `plm`.

Esse erro acontecendo, a única coisa que eu consigo pensar é que a sua fórmula está incorreta. De fato, eu não conheço esta especificação usando `y ~ a + b | . ~ a + b + c + d`

Note que isso já não funciona:

```
> model.frame.default(. ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species, data = painel)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.' not found
```

Isso tudo para dizer: Será que a sua fórmula está correta? 
Será que você não quer uma fórmula do tipo: `Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species + ano.mes` em que o modelo roda normalmente?